# Hibernate envers @embeddable property level audit

Tags: hibernate-envers

I'm using *Hibernate 5.2.14.Final* and *Envers 5.2.14.Final* to persist a complex datamodel with revisions. I'm trying to track entity changes at property level.
My datamodel has few `@Embedded` entities as a fields in main class. Each of embeddable classes annotated as `@Embeddable`. All data for main entity and for embedded entities saved in one table in database.
My main entity annotated as `@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)`.
In `_AUD` table all fields are audited correctly, but `Envers` populates `_MOD` flags only for main entity and not for `@Embedded` entities.
I will be grateful for any suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: Presently in 5.x, Envers should be creating a `componentProperty_MOD` field and setting that value to `1` if the component is changed but it does not track any `MOD` fields for the actual sub-properties of an embeddable.  If you're noticing something otherwise its definitely a bug.  In 6.0, we intend to extend that support to also track changes for embeddable properties if the embeddable is deemed modified.

Comment: Thanks for your update... Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no; not without changing the Envers source code to deal with this use case.

Comment: Hi Naros, can you look into it https://stackoverflow.com/q/51501043/5114356. Please help me