# hibernate envers throw entity not found exception, when audit table doesn't have record with ID

Tags: hibernate-envers

Account Entity

```
@Getter
@Accessors(chain = true, fluent = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
@ToString(of = {"customerName"}, callSuper = true)
@Entity

@Table(name = "ACCOUNTS", 
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = UNQ_CUSTOMER_NAME, columnNames = { "CUSTOMER_NAME" }),
    indexes = { 
            @Index(name = IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY, columnList = "CUSTOMER_ENTITY")  
    }
)

public class Account extends BaseAutoAssignableVersionableEntity<String, Long> implements Diffable<Account> {

public static final String CUSTOMER_ENTITY = "Customer Entity";
public static final String CUSTOMER_REPORTING_MANAGER = "Customer Reporting Manager";
public static final String CUSTOMER_NAME = "Customer Name";
public static final String ACCOUNT_MANAGER = "Account Manager";
public static final String CITY = "City";
public static final String CUSTOMER_TIME_TRACKING = "Customer Time Tracking";

@NotNull
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_NAME", nullable = false, length = 150)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
private String customerName; // Unique

@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 4)
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_GROUP", nullable = false, length = 4)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
private String customerGroup;

// @NotNull
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ENTITY", nullable = true, length = 150)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
private String customerEntity; // customer entity is optional and can be same for multiple accounts

@NotNull
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_REPORTING_MANAGER", nullable = false, length = 150)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
private String customerReportingManager;

@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_TIME_TRACKING", length = 1)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
private boolean customerTimeTracking = false;

@NotNull
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_MANAGER_CODE", unique = false, nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = FK_ACCOUNTS_MGR_RESOURCE_CODE))
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true, targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED, modifiedColumnName = "ACCOUNT_MANAGER_CODE_MOD")
private Resource accountManager;
```

Resource Entity

```
@Getter
@Accessors(chain = true, fluent = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(of = { "name" }, callSuper = true)
@Entity
// @formatter:off
@Table(name = "RESOURCES", 
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = UNQ_RESOURCES_LOGIN_ID, columnNames = {"LOGIN_ID"}),
        @UniqueConstraint(name = UNQ_RESOURCES_EMAIL_ID, columnNames = {"EMAIL_ID"}),
        @UniqueConstraint(name = UNQ_RESOURCES_PAYROLL_ID, columnNames = {"PAYROLL_ID"})
    },
    indexes = { 
        @Index(name = IDX_RESOURCES_NAME, columnList = "NAME")    
    }
)
// @formatter:on
public class Resource extends BaseAutoAssignableVersionableEntity<String, Long> implements Diffable<Resource> {

public static final String EMAIL_ID = "Email ID";
public static final String GRAYT_HR_ID = "Grayt HR ID";
public static final String NAME = "Name";
public static final String GENEDER = "Gender";
public static final String DESIGNATION = "Designation";
public static final String TYPE_OF_RESOURCE = "Resource Type";
public static final String STATUS_OF_RESOURCE = "Resource Status";
public static final String BASE_LOCATION = "Base Location";
public static final String DEPUTED_LOCATION = "Deputed Location";
public static final String PRIMARY_SKILLS = "Primary Skills";
public static final String SECONDARY_SKILLS = "Secondary Skills";
public static final String EXPECTED_JOINING_DATE = "Expected Joining Date";
public static final String ACTUAL_JOINING_DATE = "Actual Joining Date";
public static final String EXIST_DATE = "Exist Date";

// @Pattern(regexp = REGEX_LOGIN_ID, message = MESSAGE_LOGIN_ID_INVALID)
// @NotNull(message = MESSAGE_LOGIN_ID_MANDATORY)
@Column(name = "LOGIN_ID", nullable = false, length = 100)
private String loginId;

@Email(message = MESSAGE_EMAIL_INVALID)
@Column(name = "EMAIL_ID", nullable = true, length = 255)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
private String emailId;

@Pattern(regexp = REGEX_PAYROLL_ID, message = MESSAGE_PAYROLL_ID_INVALID)
@Column(name = "PAYROLL_ID", nullable = true, length = 100)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true, modifiedColumnName = "PAYROLL_ID_MOD")
private String payrollId;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 255)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
private String name;

@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "GENDER", nullable = false, length = 10)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
private Gender gender;

@NotNull
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "DESIGNATION_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = FK_RESOURCES_DESIGNATION_ID))
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true, targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED, modifiedColumnName = "DESIGNATION_ID_MOD")
private Designation designation;

@NotNull
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "EMP_TYPE_CODE", unique = false, nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = FK_RESOURCES_EMP_TYPE_CODE))
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true, targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED, modifiedColumnName = "EMP_TYPE_CODE_MOD")
private EmploymentType employmentType;

public boolean isFTE() {
    return (this.employmentType.equals(EmploymentType.fullTimeEmployee()));
}

@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true,  modifiedColumnName = "EMP_STATUS_ID_MOD")
@OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_status_id", unique = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = FK_RESOURCES_EMP_STATUS_ID))
private EmploymentStatus employmentStatus;
```

When i'm creating the account, used the existing resource as account manager and created successfully. Then fetch the history successfully. But unfortunately deleted the resource record in resource_aud table, then fetch the history. It's throwing below error

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.gspann.itrack.domain.model.staff.Resource with id IN10000
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:159)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:244)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:166)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:268)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73)
at com.gspann.itrack.domain.model.staff.Resource_$$_jvst4e_12.name(Resource_$$_jvst4e_12.java)
at com.gspann.itrack.domain.model.business.Account.diff(Account.java:328)
at com.gspann.itrack.domain.model.business.Account.diff(Account.java:1)
at com.gspann.itrack.domain.model.common.audit.util.AuditQueryUtils.getAllRevisionById(AuditQueryUtils.java:66)
at com.gspann.itrack.domain.service.impl.AccountManagementServiceImpl.getAllRevisionByAccountCode(AccountManagementServiceImpl.java:268)
```

below is the query generated by hibernate envers

```
/* select
    e__,
    r 
from
    com.gspann.itrack.domain.model.business.Account_AUD e__,
    com.gspann.itrack.audit.domain.CustomRevisionEntity r 
where
    e__.REVTYPE <> :_p0 
    and e__.originalId.code = :_p1 
    and e__.originalId.REV.id = r.id 
order by
    e__.originalId.REV.id asc */ select
        account_au0_.code as code1_1_0_,
        account_au0_.rev as rev2_1_0_,
        customrevi1_.id as id1_49_1_,
        account_au0_.revtype as revtype3_1_0_,
        account_au0_.customer_entity as customer4_1_0_,
        account_au0_.customer_entity_mod as customer5_1_0_,
        account_au0_.customer_group as customer6_1_0_,
        account_au0_.customer_group_mod as customer7_1_0_,
        account_au0_.customer_name as customer8_1_0_,
        account_au0_.customer_name_mod as customer9_1_0_,
        account_au0_.customer_reporting_manager as custome10_1_0_,
        account_au0_.customer_reporting_manager_mod as custome11_1_0_,
        account_au0_.customer_time_tracking as custome12_1_0_,
        account_au0_.customer_time_tracking_mod as custome13_1_0_,
        account_au0_.account_manager_code as account14_1_0_,
        account_au0_.account_manager_code_mod as account15_1_0_,
        account_au0_.country_code as country16_1_0_,
        account_au0_.country_code_mod as country17_1_0_,
        customrevi1_.last_modified_on as last_mod2_49_1_,
        customrevi1_.modified_by as modified3_49_1_,
        customrevi1_.timestamp as timestam4_49_1_ 
    from
        accounts_aud account_au0_ cross 
    join
        revinfo customrevi1_ 
    where
        account_au0_.revtype<>? 
        and account_au0_.code=? 
        and account_au0_.rev=customrevi1_.id 
    order by
        account_au0_.rev asc
```

after calling getter method of resource it's generating another resource related query like below

```
/* select
    e__ 
from
    com.gspann.itrack.domain.model.staff.Resource_AUD e__ 
where
    e__.originalId.REV.id = (
        select
            max(e2__.originalId.REV.id) 
        from
            com.gspann.itrack.domain.model.staff.Resource_AUD e2__ 
        where
            e2__.originalId.REV.id <= :revision 
            and e__.originalId.code = e2__.originalId.code
    ) 
    and e__.REVTYPE <> :_p0 
    and e__.originalId.code = :_p1 */ select
        resource_a0_.code as code1_48_,
        resource_a0_.rev as rev2_48_,
        resource_a0_.revtype as revtype3_48_,
        resource_a0_.actual_joining_date as actual_j4_48_,
        resource_a0_.actual_joining_date_mod as actual_j5_48_,
        resource_a0_.email_id as email_id6_48_,
        resource_a0_.email_id_mod as email_id7_48_,
        resource_a0_.exit_date as exit_dat8_48_,
        resource_a0_.exit_date_mod as exit_dat9_48_,
        resource_a0_.gender as gender10_48_,
        resource_a0_.gender_mod as gender_11_48_,
        resource_a0_.name as name12_48_,
        resource_a0_.name_mod as name_mo13_48_,
        resource_a0_.payroll_id as payroll14_48_,
        resource_a0_.payroll_id_mod as payroll15_48_,
        resource_a0_.utilization as utiliza16_48_,
        resource_a0_.utilization_mod as utiliza17_48_,
        resource_a0_.utilization_type as utiliza18_48_,
        resource_a0_.utilization_type_mod as utiliza19_48_,
        resource_a0_.base_loc_id as base_lo20_48_,
        resource_a0_.base_loc_id_mod as base_lo21_48_,
        resource_a0_.deputed_loc_id as deputed22_48_,
        resource_a0_.deputed_loc_id_mod as deputed23_48_,
        resource_a0_.designation_id as designa24_48_,
        resource_a0_.designation_id_mod as designa25_48_,
        resource_a0_.emp_status_id as emp_sta26_48_,
        resource_a0_.emp_status_id_mod as emp_sta27_48_,
        resource_a0_.emp_type_code as emp_typ28_48_,
        resource_a0_.emp_type_code_mod as emp_typ29_48_,
        resource_a0_.image_id as image_i30_48_,
        resource_a0_.image_id_mod as image_i31_48_ 
    from
        resources_aud resource_a0_ 
    where
        resource_a0_.rev=(
            select
                max(resource_a1_.rev) 
            from
                resources_aud resource_a1_ 
            where
                resource_a1_.rev<=? 
                and resource_a0_.code=resource_a1_.code
        ) 
        and resource_a0_.revtype<>? 
        and resource_a0_.code=?
```

below is the code to fetch the revisions

```
AuditReader auditReader = this.getAuditReader();
    return auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(clazz, selectedEntitiesOnly, selectDeletedEntities);
```

My question is, why it's referring to audit table instead of main table?

Thank in advance

Comment: If you remove the `withModifiedFlag` and `modifiedColumnName` from the annotation on the `resourceManager` property, does it still try to reference the audit table?

Comment: Hi Naros, thanks for your response. I tried with above suggestion, but still i''m getting same issue/error

Comment: I think above issue is a bug in hibernate envers. Why because, when i searched for above issue founded few bugs related to this in hibernate envers bug traker https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8093
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8051

Comment: Could you attach a test case to HHH-8051 that replicates your use case so I can confirm if the changes made in HHH-8051 address it or not for you?

Comment: Hi Naros, Here i'm adding sample code to replicating the above issue please have look https://github.com/sateeshpuvvalla/AudtingEntityObjects.git. In this project i have written test case, which contains two test methods one is create the test data and another one is the getting the revisions of account

Comment: first you try without deleting the address row in address audit table, this time no issue or errors. second time try with deleting the row in address audit table, this time you will get an error like above issue. Please let me know if have any issues.